# Notification of my examples being deleted

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-examples, deleted-examples

Having spent some considerable time writing an example on [Regular Expressions in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/320/strings-and-characters/7764/regular-expressions#t=2016080906321037) I was really surprised when I couldn't refer to it today.

[It turns out it was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/80770) (even though it had a couple of upvotes) because it was not appropriate for the topic.

Can I be notified if my work is deleted? So I can repurpose it or move somewhere else? Even if I just put it on my own blog it means the time isn't completely wasted.

Comment: Given you don't get notified when your answers are deleted I wouldn't hold your breath.  (At least you can easily get your example back!)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Usually answers do not get deleted, in Documentation however, deletion is just another kind of edit (of which you are notified in answers) and one should get notified about it. It's just a different situation and more similar to an edit. The request is very good in order to keep quality high and the contributors happy.

Comment: @Trilarion I fully support this request; I'm just pessimistic about its chances.

Answer (score 6):

This really sounds like a good idea if ownership is applied to individual examples, which can typically be done for most small and/or new examples, but it would really just be an irritation with bigger ones.

However, the creator of an example is just *one* major contributor, and it's hard to say that the creator of [Introduction to Java Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/91/lambda-expressions/2353/introduction-to-java-lambdas) "owns" the entire example. Because of this, one must assume that all major contributors would need to all be notified. I'll use that for the example below.

Suppose someone is repeatedly vandalizing everything in sight, possibly through the use of sock puppets to evade edit bans. Due to robo-reviewing, one or more is approved. I can guarantee you that someone with a silver tag badge will notice the deletion and roll it back within a few hours, even without this feature. Meanwhile, quite a few users have just received a pointless notification.

Here's a couple other ways to find out:

- Check for sudden drops in rep. This only works if it's received an upvote or two.
- Watch the activity tab of that tag's dashboard. Topic and example deletion will show up there, and if it isn't deleted within a few days, it likely won't be until after it gets upvoted and the first method can be used.